# Error generated when trying to use indirect in Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to execute the following function

```
function setFormula() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange('C2'); //Set the cell here
 range.setFormula('=VLOOKUP(C$1,INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!$B$5:$E$200"),3,FALSE)')
```

I receive the following error:

> Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 68 file: Frontline Output.gs

I tried the same function with

```
range.setFormula('=2+3')
```

and it behaved as expected. I similarly tried with a hardcoded vlookup and it worked fine. I am unsure why the indirect is specifically not working.

Answer (score 0):

```js
'=VLOOKUP(C$1,INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!$B$5:$E$200"),3,FALSE)'
```

`'`(or `"`) is a delimiter: It denotes where the string formula starts and ends. You have two extra `'` inside the  string formula itself, which makes it unclear to the js engine, where exactly the string formula ends.

```
'=VLOOKUP(C$1,INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!$B$5:$E$200"),3,FALSE)'
^                       ^       ^                       ^
|                       |       |                       |
Start of string        Does it end here?             or here?
```

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The delimiter in template literals is a backtick(`). So, it doesn't usually interfere with formulas(except some query formulas, which uses backticks to escape). Use

```
`=VLOOKUP(C$1,INDIRECT("'"&$A2&"'!$B$5:$E$200"),3,FALSE)`
```

The traditional way to solve this problem

- is to escape inner quotes using  back slashes `\`:

  ```
  '=VLOOKUP(C$1,INDIRECT("\'"&$A2&"\'!$B$5:$E$200"),3,FALSE)'
  ```
- Change the delimiter to double quotes, if the inner one is single quotes and vice versa.

  ```
  "=VLOOKUP(C$1,INDIRECT(\"'\"&$A2&\"'!$B$5:$E$200\"),3,FALSE)"
  ```

  Notice escaping of all inner double quotes is still needed, but not the single quotes.

Take advantage of the syntax highlighting in the IDE. If you escaped everything correctly, the entire string formula from start to end should be of one color.

Comment: in addition to this it's also good to note that INDIRECT does not require single quotes, even if the sheet name contains spaces or other special characters. And there's also no need to absolutely reference a range when it's provided as a string.